# How to handle TOTP based authentication in performance testing tool e.g JMeter, Loadrunner?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner

I need to know if there is any way we can handle TOTP based authentication in performance testing tools like Jmeter, Loadrunner or any other? I have business process in which Amazon AWS TOTP token is required after entering username and password and i am unable to handle that process, can anyone please guide me on this?

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about [this TOTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238) then the algorithm and code snippets are described in the RFC and you can either implement it using a tool of your choice or go for one of the [existing TOTP libraries](https://github.com/search?q=totp)

Example solution for JMeter (assumes [totp.jar library](https://github.com/taimos/totp/) and [JSR223 Test Elements with Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)):

```
def key = 'JBSWY3DPEHPK3PXP'

def bytes = new org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base32().decode(key)
def hexKey = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHexString(bytes)
log.info(de.taimos.totp.TOTP.getOTP(hexKey))
```

Demo:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Work with an online Voip Provider for an instant message capable phone number for delivering your token
2. Correlate the token value from your HTTP interfaces to your VoiP IM
3. Enter password into your interface

OR

1. Lock your system down during testing to allow access only from your load generator and monitoring components
2. hard code the token value for testing
3. send back the hard coded token

Answer (score 0):

We once had a funny idea to use Micro Focus UFT and Mobile Center with connected mobile phone receiving tokens via SMS or APP together with LoadRunner to automate the whole process. It's technically feasible. However, it's a little bit heavy.